# Visual Studio 2017 - Can't install WDK extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I'm trying to get WDK installed on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, but I am getting an error claiming it doesn't support my version. WDK itself is installed, but the vsix extension won't install.

I've tried running as admin, installing an extension from Tools > Extensions & trying to install WDK again.
I also tried to install it with the command prompt(user & admin)

```
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - -------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - 15.9.3032
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - -------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - Command line parameters:
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,wdk.vsix
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - -------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - -------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - Found setup instance d3c674cd but not in launchable state.
2019-01-23 7:38:37 PM - Initializing Install...
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - Extension Details...
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Identifier         : Microsoft.Windows.DriverKit
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Name               : Windows Driver Kit
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Author             : Microsoft Corporation
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Version            : 10.0.17740.0
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Description        : A set of extensions that integrates Windows Driver development into Visual Studio.
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Locale             : en-US
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Serial Number] : 33000001FC5DB8191027A666C10000000001FC
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Not Before]    : 2017-10-05 2:26:08 PM
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Not After]     : 2018-10-05 2:26:08 PM
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : 5E940B33DEAE5945F506ADAB946A997867A40FEF
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Supported Products : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -             Version : [15.0,16.0)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -             Version : [15.0,16.0)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -             Version : [15.0,16.0)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     References         : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio MPF
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Version      : [11.0,12.0)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         MoreInfoURL  : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Nested       : No
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -         Version      : [15.0,16.0)
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - Signature Details...
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM -     Extension is signed with a valid signature.
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - 
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - Searching for applicable products...
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
2019-01-23 7:38:38 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

The installed version of Visual Studio 2017 is 15.9.4

Comment: you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer completely relevant with this question. But I had same kind of issue when I installed wdk (ver. 2004) into VS2019. It installed completely but at the time of vsix installation it showed me error. So I did these steps and it solved my issue:

1. Restarted the operating system (important)
2. Ran the wdk.vsix file from ..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2019